# preg_match special character like Turkish and other

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using following code for getting url match but when I use some special character like Turkish for example `ülke`, `aşk` then I can not get any request. but if I use `ulke` , `ask` then the I can get a result.

Anyone can tell me what is the issue here ?

```
$request_uri = 'https://www.weburl.com/hashtag/ulke'; // working fine
$request_uri = 'https://www.weburl.com/hashtag/ülke'; // no result

if (preg_match('~/(hashtag)/([[\w.-]+)~', $request_uri, $match)) {
   $pageFor = $match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the `u` modifier to tell `preg_match` to treat strings as UTF-8:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

```
$request_uri = 'https://www.weburl.com/hashtag/ülke';

if (preg_match('~/(hashtag)/([[\w.-]+)~u', $request_uri, $match)) {
   $pageFor = $match[2];
}

echo $pageFor; //ülke
```

Comment: @anubhava You are a very good person. Stay like this all the time, sir.

Comment: @anubhava can you please check my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040774/some-server-giving-500-internal-server-error